# How to print Google Visualization API Line chart in Razor/MVC3 using javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, charts, google-visualization

I could able to display the chart using google api, but unable to print using javascript. The chart I am printing is using the  tags with id="chart_div". Please help.